# dispatching action in redux-saga is not fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am studying redux-saga and I want to fetch data from :

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

and in my redux folder I have the fallowing:

(it can be checked in this github repository
https://github.com/jotasenator/redux-saga-fetching-example/tree/main/src)

```
\src\redux\api.js

import axios from 'axios'

export const loadPostApi = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
}
```

the get request to the address in question

```
src\redux\app.actions.js

export const loadPostStart = () => ({
    type: 'LOAD_POST_START',

})
export const loadPostSuccess = (posts) => ({
    type: 'LOAD_POST_SUCCESS',
    payload: posts,
})
export const loadPostFail = (error) => ({
    type: 'LOAD_POST_FAIL',
    payload: error,
})
```

those are the actions functions

```
src\redux\app.reducer.js

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    posts: [],
    errors: null,
}

export const appReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_POST_START':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case 'LOAD_POST_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            }
        case 'LOAD_POST_FAIL':
            return {
                ...state,
                errors: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

the reducer of the fetching, updating state,

```
src\redux\counterReducer.js

import { types } from "./types";

const initialState = {
    value: 0
}

export const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.adicionar:
            return {
                ...state,
                value: state.value + 1
            }

        case types.resetear:
            return {
                ...state,
                value: 0
            }

        case types.restar:
            return {
                ...state,
                value: state.value - 1
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

this is the reducer of the counter app, with different approach, types are isolated in another file

```
src\redux\rootReducer.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { counterReducer } from './counterReducer'
import { appReducer } from './app.reducer'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counterReducer,
    appReducer
})
```

the rootReducer for gathering the reducers

```
src\redux\sagas.js

import { put, takeLatest, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { loadPostApi } from './api'
import { loadPostFail, loadPostSuccess } from './app.actions'

export function* onLoadPostStartAsync() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(loadPostApi)
        yield put(loadPostSuccess(response.data))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(loadPostFail(error))

    }
}

export function* onLoadPost() {
    yield takeLatest('LOAD_POST_START', onLoadPostStartAsync)

}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield ([
        onLoadPost(),
    ])
}
```

saga onLoadPostStartAsync called by saga onLoadPost inside rootSaga

```
src\redux\store.js

import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";

import rootSaga from "./sagas";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const composeEnhancers = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

this is the store with the redux_devtool_extension, the reducers, and running rootSaga

```
src\redux\types.js

export const types = {
    adicionar: 'ADICIONAR',
    resetear: 'RESETEAR',
    restar: 'RESTAR'
}
```

those are the types of the counterApp reducer

```
src\Counter.js

import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const Counter = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { value } = useSelector(state => state.counterReducer)

  const handleAdicionar = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADICIONAR' })
  }
  const handleResetear = () => {
    (value !== 0) && dispatch({ type: 'RESETEAR' })
  }
  const handleRestar = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'RESTAR' })
  }
  console.log(value)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAdicionar}>Adicionar</button>
      {' '}
      <button onClick={handleResetear}>Resetear</button>
      {' '}
      <button onClick={handleRestar}>Restar</button>
      <hr />

    </div>
  )
}
```

this is the Counter component, it works ok

```
src\Fetching.js

import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { loadPostStart } from './redux/app.actions'


export const Fetching = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const fetchPost = () => {
        dispatch(loadPostStart())
    }

    const state = useSelector(state => state.appReducer)
    console.log(state)


    return (
        <>
            <h1>Fetching from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</h1>
            <button onClick={fetchPost}>Fetching</button>
            {
                !state.loading && state.posts.map((post) => (
                    <li key={post.id}><h2>{post.title}</h2></li>

                ))
            }

        </>
    )
}
```

the Fetching component click on the button calls fetchPost function who dispatch loadPostStart() function which is the same of dispatching {type: 'LOAD_POST_START'}, but nothing happens here when clicking, not fetch nothing from here https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
src\index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Unificator } from './Unificator';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Unificator />
  </Provider>,


  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

component Unificator has Counter and Fetching component

```
src\Unificator.js

import React from 'react'
import { Counter } from './Counter'
import { Fetching } from './Fetching'

export const Unificator = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Counter />
            <Fetching />

        </div>
    )
}
```

as you can see is about of two reducers, one is the famous counter, and the another one is the fetching issue,  do not know what is happening that is not fetching the data

obviously, i am doing something wrong here...don t see where

Comment: Does the saga get triggered?

Comment: how can I know that?, I could say no, but dispatching is ok, can see it at redux-devTools

Answer (score 0):

Axio returns promise, You need to capture that and return. Please try replacing below code.

```
export const loadPostApi = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
    .then((response) => {
         console.log('Response', response);
         return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
         console.log('error', error);
    })
}
```

Comment: nothing is happened. I think is fair to say that loadPostApi is not being called

Comment: Please check Dev tools->Network tab if api call is happening or not.

Comment: is not happening

Comment: I think you need to inject saga and reducer into your component. Please try useInjectorSaga and useInjectorReducer in your components.